# Get element by id issue?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, fadein, getelementbyid

I am trying to fade a box in by using an image with a `onclick` command. But I am lost as to why it's not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code:

```
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
   #box { background:#999; width:500px; height:500px;opacity:0; }
</style>
</head>

  <div id="box"><id="box"></div>
  <div id="img"><img src="img.png" width="37" height="28" id="img"></div>


<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("img","box");
    // attach event handler
   "img".onclick = function(){
      fadeIn( "img", 400 );
      this.onclick = null;
    };

    function setOpacity( obj, value ) {
      if ( obj ) {
        obj.style.opacity = value / 100;
        obj.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=' + value + ')';
        obj.style.zoom    = 1;
      }
    }

    // makes an element to fade in
    function fadeIn( dom, interval, delay ) {

          interval  = interval || 1000;
          delay     = delay    || 10;

      var opacity   = 0,
          start     = Number(new Date()),
          op_per_ms = 100 / interval;

      if ( typeof dom === "string" ) {
        dom = document.getElementById( dom );
      }

      function step() {

        var now     = Number(new Date()),
            elapsed = now - start;
            opacity = elapsed * op_per_ms;

        setOpacity( dom, opacity );

        if ( elapsed < interval )
          setTimeout( step, delay );
        else
          setOpacity( dom, 100 );
      }

      setTimeout( step, delay );
    }

</script>
```

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is so much easier. You simply use `$('#someElement').fadeIn()` to fade in an element. If you can, I suggest you use jQuery for animations like this. And by the way, `<id ="box">` is not valid HTML,  `"img".onclick` is what? You're supposed to do: `elem.onclick` which would be the whole point of the `elem` variable.

Comment: Well, lots of problems here. First, `<id="box">` isn't valid HTML. getElementById only takes 1 parameter, the id.

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` or `+new Date()` works just as well as using  `Number(new Date())`, by the way. Next, you're "attaching your event handler" to a string, not an element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElementById does not have more than 1 argument

```
var elem = document.getElementById("img");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("box");
```

Also your IE event handler is calling a method from a String.

```
elem.onclick = function(){
  fadeIn(this, 400 );
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help everybody! I understand it a lot more now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making two errors within this first piece of code:

```
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("img","box");
    // attach event handler
   "img".onclick = function(){
      fadeIn( "img", 400 );
      this.onclick = null;
    };
```

First of all:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("img","box");
```

is wrong because the function `getElementById` just takes one parameter. If you want to get two elements, you should use two different calls:

```
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var box = document.getElementById("box");
```

Secondly what's this?

```
"img".onclick = function(){
```

I think you meant this:

```
elem.onclick = function(){
```

That with the first correction becomes:

```
    img.onclick = function(){
      fadeIn( "img", 400 );
      this.onclick = null;
    };

    box.onclick = function(){
      fadeIn( "box", 400 );
      this.onclick = null;
    };
```